# Disable dismissing a notification using "clear all", but still can swipe?

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to allow a user to dismiss a notification by swiping it, but not allow it to be dismissed using the "Clear All" button?

I've searched SO and the web for a solution, but almost every question and answer seems to be related to either using the `setOngoing(`) method or setting the `FLAG_NO_CLEAR`.  These solutions prevent the user from dismissing the notification using the swipe gesture.

The closest answer I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678948/android-delete-notification-only-when-touched-not-throuch-clear-all-button).

I cannot use the "touch" or "click" event (which would fire the `ContentIntent`) because that intent does something different in my app than the `DeleteIntent`.

I would prefer a clean API call (i.e. something like `setNoClearAll(true)` or somesuch), but I would be satisfied if there were some way to distinguish whether my notification was dismissed using a swipe gesture or a clear all button.  Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Custom notification layout with an [X] button in corner and `setOngoing(true)`. You can assign custom pending intent to the button. The notification won't be cleared by Clear all and it can't be swiped away.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Interesting idea but I'd rather not force my user to learn a new way to dismiss notifications.

Comment: Well then the answer to "Is it possible to allow a user to dismiss a notification by swiping it, but not allow it to be dismissed using the "Clear All" button?" is a No. :(

Comment: @EugenPechanec I'm afraid you are right.  post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to allow a user to dismiss a notification by swiping it, but not allow it to be dismissed using the "Clear All" button?

I'm afraid that's not possible.

#### Alternative

I suggest using a custom notification layout with an [X] button in corner and `setOngoing(true)`. You can assign custom pending intent to the button. The notification won't be cleared by clear all button and it can't be swiped away but the user still has means to dismiss the notification.

Take inspiration from media style notification on Android 4:

[image: Standard notification]
[image: Expanded notification]